# symfony doctrine authentication bad credentials

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to follow the documentation but can't get it to work. I keep getting "Bad credentials" when trying to use the login form.

Here is my security.yml file

```
security:
    encoders:
        MyCompany\MyPoroject\UserBundle\Entity\User:
          algorithm: sha1
          encode_as_base64: false
          iterations: 1

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        administrators:
            entity: { class: MyCompanyMyProjectUserBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

This is the code i've used to create some dummy users

```
    $factory  = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $user     = new User;
    $encoder  = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $password = $encoder->encodePassword('testing', $user->getSalt());

    $user->setPassword($password)
         ->setEmail('test@gmail.com')
         ->setUsername('testing');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

Here is my User class

```
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    private $id;

    private $username;

    private $salt;

    private $password;

    private $email;

    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the roles granted to the user.
     *
     * <code>
     * public function getRoles()
     * {
     *     return array('ROLE_USER');
     * }
     * </code>
     *
     * Alternatively, the roles might be stored on a ``roles`` property,
     * and populated in any number of different ways when the user object
     * is created.
     *
     * @return Role[] The user roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }

    /**
     * Returns the password used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * This should be the encoded password. On authentication, a plain-text
     * password will be salted, encoded, and then compared to this value.
     *
     * @return string The password
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set salt
     *
     * @param string $salt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set is_active
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get is_active
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * String representation of object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.serialize.php
     * @return string the string representation of the object or null
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
                $this->id,
                $this->username,
                $this->salt,
                $this->password,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * (PHP 5 &gt;= 5.1.0)<br/>
     * Constructs the object
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/serializable.unserialize.php
     * @param string $serialized <p>
     * The string representation of the object.
     * </p>
     * @return void
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->salt,
            $this->password,
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }
}
```

My Security controller

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } else {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }

        return $this->render(
            'MyCompanyMyProjectUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }

    public function adminAction()
    {
        return $this->render('MyCompanyMyProjectUserBundle:Security:admin.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This is the record in the database i'm attempting to login with using `testing` as both the username and password.

```
id: 3
username(25): testing
salt(32): 87a449194ebfe80bfa9f59da53dab0ea
password(64): dc724af18fbdd4e59189f5fe768a5f8311527050
email(60):  test@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you missed return statement in **getSalt()** and **getPassword()** methods